# Frisby.js not POSTing to API correctly?

Tags: json, rest, post, frisby.js

I can GET with Frisby just fine, but I can't seem to POST with it.  I've used Postman to ensure the POST is valid, but it always returns an error with Frisby.  (The error is not helpful...the api only sends 404 errors for everything.)  Here's the code I'm using:

```
.frisby.create('test post')
.post('http://localhost/api', {
    "data": {
        "name": "Jackie L Smith",
        "birthdate": "2007-08-14",
        "relationship": "child",
        "boolVar": false
    }
}, {json: true}, {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }})
.expectStatus(204)
.toss();
```

For the record, the api's success code is 204 for some reason.  Could someone tell me why it's not POSTing?

Comment: There was no error.  It just never posted.

Comment: From my understanding, if you already are using `{json: true}` it is not necesary to use `application/json` header